# how to add a layout file dynamically

Tags: android, android-layout

I have this layout file containing the details of a location for a user
the user is supposed to have 1 to 3 locations, depending upon the condition i need to add 1 to 3 location forms

[image]

Can anyone tell how I can add this xml layout file to other layout files dynamically?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout 
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/container"
        android:padding="2dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/upperBox"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        >
        <RelativeLayout 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/container_inner"
        android:padding="1dp"
        >

            <TableLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:background="@color/white"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:scrollbars="vertical" >

                <TextView
                    style="@style/footerText"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/tracking_settings" />

                <TableRow
                    android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/locationName"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/location_name" />

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/editTextLocationName"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:inputType="text" >

                        <requestFocus />
                    </EditText>
                </TableRow>

                <TableRow
                    android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/address"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/address" />

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/editextAddress"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:inputType="text" />
                </TableRow>

                <TableRow
                    android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/alertPref"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/alert_preference" />

                    <Spinner
                        android:id="@+id/spinnerAlertPref"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:entries="@array/alert_pref_arrays"
                        android:prompt="@string/alert_pref_prompt" />
                </TableRow>

                <TableRow
                    android:id="@+id/tableRow4"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/frequency"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/frequency" />

                    <Spinner
                        android:id="@+id/spinnerFreq"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:entries="@array/freq_arrays"
                        android:prompt="@string/freq_prompt" />
                </TableRow>

                <TableRow
                    android:id="@+id/tableRow5"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/TrackBetween"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/track_between" />

                    <Spinner
                        android:id="@+id/spinnerTimeFrom"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:entries="@array/time_arrays"
                        android:prompt="@string/time_prompt" />
                </TableRow>

                <TableRow
                    android:id="@+id/tableRow6"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                    <Spinner
                        android:id="@+id/spinnerTimeFrom1"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:entries="@array/am_pm_arrays"
                        android:prompt="@string/am_pm_prompt" />
                </TableRow>

                <TableRow
                    android:id="@+id/tableRow7"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/to"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/to" />

                    <Spinner
                        android:id="@+id/spinnerTimeTo"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:entries="@array/time_arrays"
                        android:prompt="@string/time_prompt" />
                </TableRow>

                <TableRow
                    android:id="@+id/tableRow8"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                    <Spinner
                        android:id="@+id/spinnerTimeTo1"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:entries="@array/am_pm_arrays"
                        android:prompt="@string/am_pm_prompt" />
                </TableRow>

                <TextView
                    style="@style/footerText"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/alert_settings" />

                <TableRow
                    android:id="@+id/tableRow9"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/sexOffenderIsWithin"
                        android:layout_width="100dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/sex_offender_is_within" />

                    <Spinner
                        android:id="@+id/spinnerSexOff"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:entries="@array/sex_offender_arrays"
                        android:prompt="@string/sex_offender_prompt" />
                </TableRow>

                <TableRow
                    android:id="@+id/tableRow10"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/travelAwayFromLocation"
                        android:layout_width="100dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/travel_away_from_location" />

                    <Spinner
                        android:id="@+id/spinnerTravelAway"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:entries="@array/sex_offender_arrays"
                        android:prompt="@string/sex_offender_prompt" />
                </TableRow>

                <TableRow
                    android:id="@+id/tableRow11"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/arriveAtLocation"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/arrive_at_location" />

                    <Spinner
                        android:id="@+id/spinnerArriveAt"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:entries="@array/yes_donttrack_arrays"
                        android:prompt="@string/yes_donttrack_prompt" />
                </TableRow>

                <TableRow
                    android:id="@+id/tableRow12"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/travelByVehicle"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/travel_by_vehicle" />

                    <Spinner
                        android:id="@+id/spinnerTravelBy"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:entries="@array/yes_donttrack_arrays"
                        android:prompt="@string/yes_donttrack_prompt" />
                </TableRow>

                <TableRow
                    android:id="@+id/tableRow13"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/phonStatus"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/phon_status" />

                    <Spinner
                        android:id="@+id/spinnerPhonStatus"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:entries="@array/phon_status_arrays"
                        android:prompt="@string/phon_status_prompt" />
                </TableRow>

                <TableRow
                    android:id="@+id/tableRow14"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                    <TextView
                        style="@style/footerText"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/cancel" />

                    <TextView
                        style="@style/footerText"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:gravity="right"
                        android:text="@string/submit" />
                </TableRow>
            </TableLayout>

            </RelativeLayout>
            </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This layout file in another layout via LayoutInflater.

Suppose, You want to add this layout in your main layout. So, Take a linear layout in main layout and this list layout in main layout via `mainlayout.add(view)` , Here `view` is LayoutInflater viw.

Example :

```
private View view;
    view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.image_sub_layout,
                null);
     topicLinearLayout.addView(view); // main Layout Linear layout
```

Thanks.

Comment: a bit novice in android , can u plz elaborate the inflater part , all i got was to initialize a linear layout by id , then add the layout in to it

Comment: yeah i think i'll be able to cope over it now , thanx

Answer (score 2):

Let's suppose you have your first activity with an `main.xml`, wherein is an empty linearLayout.

Via `LayoutInflater` you can get that layout like

```
linearLayout = (LinearLayout) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.main, null);
layoutToAdd = (LinearLayout) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.layout_to_add, null);
```

Then you simply add your desired xml-layout-file to that linearLayout (Same thing for other types of layouts, single `View`s or `ViewGroup`s).

```
   linearLayout.add(layoutToAdd);
```

Or as Abdul suggested, you "cast" that desired layout into a View.

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding, you wanted the layout to contain 1-3 location forms depending on the condition that you want to implement.If you are sure that you are handling the number of Locations to be entered from the UI, then simply add the same layout three times with different id's with `Visibility`  to `GONE`. And while handling it from UI, you can change the visibility of the Layout to `view.VISIBLE` depending on your conditions from UI thread.

You can insert the code for scrollView to make your main layout to be scrollable for the end user.

Comment: well yes i have to add the location layout depending on the condition , but i cant decide how much , it may vary from 1 to 3 for diff users , add adding maximum no of locations creates the memory dump prob dats y i need to keep as min views as possible